# How can i make my Python Code more compact?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i make my Python Code more compact?
Any help will be much appericated

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
    if del_number == 2 or del_number == 4 or del_number == 6 or del_number == 8 or del_number == 10:
        print("The number you have entered is an even number")
    elif del_number > 10:
        print("Not a valid number")
    else:
        print("The number you have entered is a odd number")
except:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```

Comment: As an aside, restrict your exception handling to `except ValueError`. Your exceptions should be narrow to avoid accidentally suppressing unexpected errors and hiding bugs.

Answer (score 4):

You can shorten the even number check

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
    if del_number in (2 , 4, 6, 8, 10):
        print("The number you have entered is an even number")
    elif del_number > 10:
        print("Not a valid number")
    else:
        print("The number you have entered is a odd number")
except ValueError:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```

Or use the low bit to decide even / odd (and perhaps select the name from a list)

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
    if not 1 < del_number <= 10:
        print("Not a valid number")
    else:
        category = ["even", "odd"][del_number & 1]
        print(f"The number you have entered is a {category} number")
except ValueError:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```

Considering this a bit more, you could restrict your exception handling to the integer conversion itself to reduce the chance that you accidentally mask bugs in later code. Suppose a bug in the later tests also raised a `ValueError`. You wouldn't know until the angry reports from the field.

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
except ValueError:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
else:
    if not 1 < del_number <= 10:
        print("Not a valid number")
    else:
        category = ["even", "odd"][del_number & 1]
        print(f"The number you have entered is a {category} number")
```

Comment: I think it would be *pythonic* if you have used conditional expressions instead of iterable indexing: `"odd" if del_number & 1 else "even"`

Comment: That's another way of doing it, but not really more _pythonic_, IMHO. My method would work for categories extending beyond 1 bit, say a list with 8 entries and `del_numbers & 3`. Indexing into a list is normal stuff. I get what you are saying though, some would prefer your method.

Comment: "*say a list with 8 entries and `del_numbers & 3`*" wow, that really blew my mind. It would be great for such scenario. However, I still find it confusing because I always have to stop and think which one is selected if this expression evaluates to `True` etc.

Comment: @Asocia - yeah, different perspectives. I spent too many years in low level C with bit fields. I dream of bit fields (or hellish nightmares perhaps). I just kinda saw this as a category selection thing but your perspective of true/false is equally valid.

Comment: hahaha, I can imagine because you've also chosen `del_numbers & 1` instead of `del_numbers % 2 == 1` :)

Comment: With the `fstring` and the `category` you can make proper use of the title welcome to **MY** program. haha Nice answer and beautiful alternatives!

Comment: @CeliusStingher - We could also get rid of the intermediate `category` and just do the index in the f-string. I'm debating whether that' getting a bit obscure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo operator `%` instead of so many concatenated `or`. For information on the operator read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html).

This is the line of code to be replaced:

```
if del_number == 2 or del_number == 4 or del_number == 6 or del_number == 8 or del_number == 10:
```

This would be the replacement:

```
elif del_number % 2 == 0:
```

The reason for the `if` change to `elif` is the fact we first want to make the sure the number is `<= 10`. Therefore, our first condition `if` will test whether the number is `> 10`. If it passes that criteria, then comes the `elif` part with the modulo operator. All in all:

```
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
    if del_number > 10 or del_number < 0:
        print("Not a valid number")
    elif del_number % 2 == 0:
        print("The number you have entered is an even number")
    else:
        print("The number you have entered is a odd number")
except:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```

Comment: Not exactly. The first statement only accepts even numbers in range 1-10 while the second one accepts **any** even number.

Comment: And you would need to move the `> 10` comparison above it to catch the overflow case first.

Comment: I can easily fix that putting in the elif and switching the `>10` as the first  condition for the `if`. Thanks for the suggestions, editing the answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can make it in a more compact way

```
if del_number in range(2, 11, 2):  # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
    print("The number you have entered is an even number")
```

or

```
if del_number % 2 == 0:
    print("The number you have entered is an even number")
```

If you want to check `del_number` is even or odd

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it that way:

```py
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
except:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")

if del_number % 2 == 0 and del_number <= 10:
    print("The number you have entered is an even number")
elif del_number > 10:
    print("Not a valid number")
else:
    print("The number you have entered is a odd number")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
try:
    del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: \n"))
    if del_number % 2 == 0 and 1 < del_number < 10 :
        print("The number you have entered is an even number")
    elif del_number > 10 or del_number < 1:
        print("Not a valid number")
    else:
        print("The number you have entered is a odd number")
except:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to my program")
# This program tells if a number form 1 - 10 is even or odd
del_number = int(input("Input a number 1 - 10: "))
try:
    {
        0: lambda: print("The number you have entered is an even number"),
        1: lambda: print("The number you have entered is an odd number")
    }[del_number % 2 if 0 < del_number <= 10 else None]()
except:
    print("You have entered a letter/letters not a number 1 - 10")
```